# Auto mail isn't executing HTML tags when inserted in between email body

Tags: php, email

I have a code to make and get an auto-email from the user when he submits the form.

The code also consists of insert query to put all the data into a DB table.

However, the Insert query and auto mail work fine. data gets inserted and I receive the mail with values as well.

The code goes for that as:

```
<?php include('db.php'); ?>
<?php

$fname = $_POST['fname'];
$mname = $_POST['mname'];
$lname = $_POST['lname'];

$address = $_POST['address'];
$address2 = $_POST['address2'];
$city = $_POST['city'];
$state = $_POST['state'];
$zipcode = $_POST['zipcode'];
$country = $_POST['country'];

$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$altphone = $_POST['altphone'];

$citizenship = $_POST['citizenship'];
$visa = $_POST['visa'];
$inviteletter = $_POST['inviteletter'];
$housingassist = $_POST['housingassist'];
$im = $_POST['im'];
$status = 'open';

$university = $_POST['university'];
$univstartdate = $_POST['univstartdate'];
$univgraddate = $_POST['univgraddate'];
$univaddress = $_POST['univaddress'];
$univcity = $_POST['univcity'];
$univstate = $_POST['univstate'];
$univzipcode = $_POST['univzipcode'];
$univcountry = $_POST['univcountry'];

$usmle = implode(', ', $_POST['usmle']);
$rotationlength = $_POST['rotationlength'];
$speciality1 = $_POST['speciality1'];
$speciality2 = $_POST['speciality2'];
$speciality3 = $_POST['speciality3'];
$research = $_POST['research'];
$additional = $_POST['additional'];

$startdate = $_POST['startdate'];
$freecall = $_POST['freecall'];

$howus = $_POST['howus'];


$date = date_default_timezone_set('America/New_York');
$date = date('M-d,Y H:i:s');
$date2 = date('M-d,Y');

$conn = new mysqli ($servername, $dbusername, $dbpassword, $dbname);
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO applications (fname, mname, lname, address, address2, city, state, zipcode, country, email, phone, altphone, citizenship, visa, inviteletter, housingassist, im, university, univstartdate, univgraddate, univaddress, univcity, univstate, univzipcode, univcountry, usmle, rotationlength, speciality1, speciality2, speciality3, research, additional, startdate, freecall, howus, date, status)

VALUES ('$fname', '$mname', '$lname', '$address', '$address2', '$city', '$state', '$zipcode', '$country', '$email', '$phone', '$altphone', '$citizenship', '$visa', '$inviteletter', '$housingassist', '$im', '$university', '$univstartdate', '$univgraddate', '$univaddress', '$univcity', '$univstate', '$univzipcode', '$univcountry', '$usmle', '$rotationlength', '$speciality1', '$speciality2', '$speciality3', '$research', '$additional', '$startdate', '$freecall', '$howus', '$date2', '$status')";
if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {


$email_from = 'newyorkrotations@gmail.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Student Application";
$email_body = "First Name : $fname.\n 
               Middle Name : $mname.\n 
               Last Name : $lname.\n 
               Address : $address.\n
               Alt Address : $address2.\n 
               City : $city.\n
               State : $state.\n
               Zipcode : $zipcode.\n
               Country : $country.\n
               Email : $email.\n
               Phone : $phone.\n
               Alt Phone : $altphone.\n
               Citizenship : $citizenship.\n
               Does He Need Visa : $visa.\n
               Does He Need Invite Letter : $inviteletter.\n
               Does He Need Housing Assistance : $housingassist.\n
               He is A : $im.\n
               University : $university.\n
               College Start Date : $univstartdate.\n
               Graduation Date : $univgraddate.\n
               University Address : $univaddress.\n
               University City : $univcity.\n
               University Stqate : $univstate.\n
               University Zipcode : $univzipcode.\n
               University Country : $univcountry.\n
               Did He took Any Steps : $usmle.\n
               Requested Rotation Length : $rotationlength.\n
               Speciality #1 : $speciality1.\n
               Speciality #2 : $speciality2.\n
               Speciality #3 : $speciality3.\n
               Research : $research.\n
               Additional Services : $additional.\n
               Rotation Start Date : $startdate.\n
               Do He need physician's Free call : $freecall.\n
               How did He Reached Us : $howus.\n
               Application Submitted at : $date2.\n";

$to = "newyorkrotations@gmail.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: index.php');

}
else {
    echo "ERROR" . $sql . "<br>" . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
?>
```

However I tried with adding some HTML code in to the code so that the mail i recieve look a bit nice. But instead i get the whole code as it is in my mail . Mean the HTML gets posted to mail as just plain text.

THe code for that as:

```
$email_from = 'newyorkrotations@gmail.com';//<== update the email address
$email_subject = "Student Application";

$message = '<html><body>';
            $message .= '<img src="http://css-tricks.com/examples/WebsiteChangeRequestForm/images/wcrf-header.png" alt="Website Change Request" />';
            $message .= '<table rules="all" style="border-color: #666;" cellpadding="10">';
            $message .= "<tr style='background: #eee;'><td><strong>First Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['fname']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Middle Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['mname']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Last Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['lname']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Address:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['address']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Alt Address:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['address2']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>City:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['city']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>State:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['state']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>ZipCode:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['zipcode']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Country:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['country']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Email:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['email']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Phone:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['phone']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Alt Phone:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['altphone']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Citizenship:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['citizenship']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Does He Have Visa:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['visa']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Does He Need Invite Letter:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['inviteletter']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Does He Need Housing Assist:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['housingassist']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>He Is:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['im']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>University Name:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['university']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>University Start Date:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['univstartdate']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>University Graduation Date:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['univgraddate']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>University Address:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['univaddress']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>University City:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['univcity']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>University State:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['univstate']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Universtiy Zipcode:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['univzipcode']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>University Country:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['univcountry']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Steps Taken:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['usmle']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Rotation Length:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['rotationlength']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Speciality #1:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['speciality1']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Speciality #2:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['speciality2']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Speciality #3:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['speciality3']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Research:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['research']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Additional:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['additional']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Rotation Start Date:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['startdate']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>Does He Need A Free Call:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['freecall']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "<tr><td><strong>How did he find us:</strong> </td><td>" . strip_tags($_POST['howus']) . "</td></tr>";
            $message .= "</table>";
            $message .= "</body></html>";

$to = "newyorkrotations@gmail.com";//<== update the email address
$headers = "From: $email \r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: $email \r\n";
//Send the email!
mail($to,$email_subject,$message,$headers);
//done. redirect to thank-you page.
header('Location: index.php');
```

Just replace the $email_body with $message with some HTML code.

But it executed as text instead.

Any Help is Appreciatede..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't given proper headers check this example

```
<?php
$to = 'maryjane@email.com';
$subject = 'Marriage Proposal';
$from = 'peterparker@email.com';

// To send HTML mail, the Content-type header must be set
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";

// Create email headers
$headers .= 'From: '.$from."\r\n".
    'Reply-To: '.$from."\r\n" .
    'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();

// Compose a simple HTML email message
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1 style="color:#f40;">Hi Jane!</h1>';
$message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">Will you marry me?</p>';
$message .= '</body></html>';

// Sending email
if(mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers)){
    echo 'Your mail has been sent successfully.';
} else{
    echo 'Unable to send email. Please try again.';
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add HTML content type to your $headers

```
$headers .= "Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8\r\n";
```